# Javascript slice array based on multiples of 2

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a slice method for an array, say you have a list of 7 items, but initially it shows 2 items. How would you show more items based on each function click ?

like show 3 more, show 2 more, show 1 more, until there is no more items to show.

https://jsbin.com/ratohehuyi/edit?js,console

I'm stuck on writing the logic, this is just pseudocode

```
  const arr = ['blueberries', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'bananas', 'kiwis', 'apples', 'coconuts']

  const arrNum = 2

  console.log(arrNum)

  const showMore = (arr) => {
    return arr.slice(0, arrNum * 2 ) // this should increment i think based on each function click 
  }

  console.log(showMore(arr))
```

Comment: > `The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.`

Comment: you'll want to use `.slice`

Comment: ok i used it, but still have some issues with the logic.

Comment: use pop or shift.  it's easier to reason about.  splice should work though

Comment: Would you be able to provide an answer, this is a similar implementation to the way facebook/instagram does their comments.

Comment: sounds like you're trying to build a `Stack/Queue`

Comment: that sounds like a more of a complex data structure approach, and not a simple array slicing approach.

Comment: wording is a little confusing.  you say multiple of 2 but then say 3 more.  can you give examples of successive outputs?  the code doesn't really show much because it just slices 0-4.  actually that answer makes a lot of sense now.  looks like he solved it, although imo it's a lot more verbose than it needs to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would you show more items based on each function click ?

You have to increment slice of array taken with each click call.

**Example**

```js
const array = ['blueberries', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'bananas', 'kiwis', 'apples', 'coconuts']

let arrNum = 0;

const listElement = document.querySelector("#list");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");

const showMore = () => {

  arrNum = arrNum + 2;
  const sublist = array.slice(0, arrNum);
  
  let first = listElement.firstElementChild; 
  while (first) { 
    first.remove(); 
    first = listElement.firstElementChild; 
  } 
  
  for(let item of sublist) {
    const itemElement = document.createElement("li");
    itemElement.textContent = item;
    listElement.appendChild(itemElement);
  }
  
  if(sublist.length === array.length) {
    button.style.display = "none";
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", showMore);

showMore();
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
<button id="button">Show more</button>
```

--Edit

Now when I think of it. This approach is stupid as we are deleting everything with every call.

Here's a bit of improvement.

```js
const array = ['blueberries', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'bananas', 'kiwis', 'apples', 'coconuts']

let from = 0;
let to = 2;

const listElement = document.querySelector("#list");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");

const showMore = () => {

  const sublist = array.slice(from, to);
  from = to;
  to = to + 2;
  
  for(let item of sublist) {
    const itemElement = document.createElement("li");
    itemElement.textContent = item;
    listElement.appendChild(itemElement);
  }
  
  if([...listElement.children].length === array.length) {
    button.style.display = "none";
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", showMore);

showMore();
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
<button id="button">Show more</button>
```

Comment: appreciate this. This was really meant to be in a react component, just made this as a javascript example so that i get an idea of how to implement it

Comment: Updated answer. You have two solutions. Like red pill and blue pill. The latter is red

Comment: @JózefPodlecki if I turned that into a one liner, would I trigger deja vu?

Comment: @user120242 that would be like going from SSJ2 to SSJ3.

Answer (score 1):

#### Note: Adding for supplementary explanation of OP

The issue is that the increment in the splice method was multiplying by 2

e.g. `array.splice(0, arrNum * 2)`

This `arrNum*2` shifts the position to the right every time arrNum is incremented by a factor of 2.

The effect of using splice in this is similar as to a Queue (fifo) - however, since the values returned on showMore aren't being logged, this is most likely where the confusion lies.

Alternatively, if you wanted to implement a stack (LIFO), you can use the `pop` method, or replace the position of `splice(<index>)` to be the offset at the end of the array.

```js
const arr = ['blueberries', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'bananas', 'kiwis', 'apples', 'coconuts']

const showMore = (arr, num) => {
  return arr.splice(0, num) 
}

let firstTwo = showMore(arr, 2) //? [ 'blueberries', 'oranges' ]
console.log(arr)  //? [ 'grapes', 'bananas', 'kiwis', 'apples', 'coconuts' ] 

let nextThree = showMore(arr, 3) //? [ 'grapes', 'bananas', 'kiwis' ]

console.log(arr); //? [ 'apples', 'coconuts' ] 

let last = showMore(arr, 2) //? [ 'apples', 'coconuts' ]
console.log(arr) //? []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a function that takes an increment and an array and return a function that returns bigger slices of the original array after each call.

```js
const slicer =
  (inc, arr, count = 0) =>
    () => arr.slice(0, count+=inc);
    
const show_more = (get_data) => () => {
  console.log(get_data());
};
    
document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', show_more(slicer(2, arr)));
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [ 'blueberries'
            , 'oranges'
            , 'grapes'
            , 'bananas'
            , 'kiwis'
            , 'apples'
            , 'coconuts'
            ];
</script>

<button>show more</button>
```